# How to send Unicode JSON over HTTP?

Tags: json, http, unicode, encoding, utf-8

[RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) section 3 says

> JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is UTF-8.

> Since the first two characters of a JSON text will always be ASCII
> characters [RFC0020], it is possible to determine whether an octet
> stream is UTF-8, UTF-16 (BE or LE), or UTF-32 (BE or LE) by looking
> at the pattern of nulls in the first four octets.

> ```
>        00 00 00 xx  UTF-32BE
> ```

```
       00 xx 00 xx  UTF-16BE
       xx 00 00 00  UTF-32LE
       xx 00 xx 00  UTF-16LE
       xx xx xx xx  UTF-8
```

I'm serving a UTF-8 encoded JSON string of [U+20AC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20AC/index.htm) as application/json.

```
$ curl -D - http://localhost:8000/test.json
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.7.6
Date: Fri, 15 Jan 2016 09:24:53 GMT
Content-type: application/json
Content-Length: 6
Last-Modified: Fri, 15 Jan 2016 09:23:13 GMT

"€"

$ curl -s http://localhost:8000/test.json | hexdump
0000000 e222 ac82 0a22                         
0000006
```

But both Chrome *and* Firefox seemed to be using some other encoding, as both show

```
"â‚¬"
```

If change the `Content-Type` to `application/json; charset=utf-8`, they show the expected result.

But `charset` is a made up addition to `application/json`, and I'm not sure if it is legal to add extra parameters to it.

This is all rather confusing.

Is there a bug somewhere? What's the correct way for me to transmit UTF-8 encoded JSON documents over HTTP?

Comment: _"Since the first two characters of a JSON text will always be ASCII characters..."_ Note that this isn't true anymore. [RFC 7159](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#appendix-A) also allows strings as "JSON text" which can have a non-ASCII characters in the second position.

Comment: Nit: U+0080 isn't the € sign; but that's unrelated to the actual problem.

Comment: @JulianReschke, correct. For some reason http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0080/index.html showed €. I fixed it to U+20AC.

Comment: It's because some fonts indeed have it there, and that's because Microsoft's flavor of ISO-8859-1 indeed has it there...

Comment: @nwellnhof normally the first two characters of a JSON string are {" or [" or [{ ... all of which are ASCII and 7-bit at that. Is JSON now supporting alternate delimiters?

Comment: @KeithTyler According to RFC 7159, a plain string like `"ü"` is valid JSON.

Answer (score 4):

Your response is correct. `charset` shouldn't do anything on `application/json` as that's a parameter of `text/` types; a JSON processor will ignore it.

The problem is that Chrome and Firefox aren't acting as JSON processors here; they aren't parsing or validating anything in the response content. They're falling back to their regular old text viewers to display the content as if it were `text/plain`, on the premise that this is better than nothing.

Unfortunately plain text viewers have their own rules about guessing encodings that do not match JSON's in-content-signalling-only rules. IE's behaviour of treating `application/json` as an unknown binary type and prompting you to download it is actually the more-correct thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The `content-type` header field you are using is perfectly valid.</strike>

The part of RFC 2616 [that defines header fields in HTTP 1.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) treats adding the encoding after a semicolon as a valid way to go.

If you do not specify a character set, the browser will either use the defined default (ISO-8859-1, this happened in your case) or, depending on its settings, try to auto-detect the character set.

As Julian points out (and you probably already knew) the `application/json` content type doesn't require, nor need an addition of `charset`.

It appears that browsers are handling `application/json` responses incorrectly and falling back to ISO-8859-1 even though they shouldn't.

- Here is an [open bug report for Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=438464)
- Here is a [discussion about making the same server-side change you did](https://github.com/request/request/issues/383)

Comment: It's valid, but meaningless. application/json doesn't have a charset parameter. See last sentence in <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7159.html#ianacons>.

Comment: @Julian I see! Then it seems like neither browser is doing the right thing here

Comment: Apparently fixed in Firefox 46; see <https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1166558>